# visual studio gives undeclared identifier error

Tags: c++

my project was working fine and then when i change something in another header file i suddenly got this error:

**Error C2065   'map': undeclared identifier**

although i did `#include <map>`

*part of Game.h:*

```
#include <map>

class Game{

    Game();

}
```

*the line which gives me the error in Game.cpp:*

```
_results.insert(map<std::string, int>::value_type(_players[i]->getUsername(), 0));
```

**this code line worked fine ! until some point**

Comment: always use `std::` before names from the standard headers.  [It makes life easier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: The code you've pasted won't even compile (you're missing a semicolon after `}`). Please post a full example.

Comment: I recommend using std::make_pair() instead of map<std::string, int>::value_type btw.

Comment: Silly question, do you have `#include <string>` as one of your includes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that at one point, you either had a class named `map` in the global namespace, which provided an interface similar to `std::map`, or more likely, you were relying on a `using namespace std;` directive that has since been removed (whether unintentionally or not; perhaps someone else had one in a header you were using, but removed it when they realised that was a bad idea).  Either put a using-directive for `std` or a using-declaration for `std::map` in the code block containing that line, or explicitly use `std::map` whenever you want to use the C++ standard library `map` class; the latter is recommended, because it makes code clearer and cleaner.

If you were using a custom `map` class before, check that its header is still `#include`d, and that it doesn't run into the same namespace issue.

Comment: #include <string>
using namespace std;

all tstrings are undeclared under visual stupidity 2003, HALLLLLP.